# Flipping the contents of a file from bottom to top except for the first line

Tags: python

I'm trying to flip the lines upside down except the first line:
example:

```
Header
first 
second 
third
```

The output with the code below is:

```
third
second
first
Header
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
Header
third
second
first
```

Code is below:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for l in reversed(lines):
        f.write(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you're after:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

firstline = lines[0] # get the first line from the file
lines.pop(0) # remove the first line from the lines list, since it's stored separately

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(firstline) # write the first line to the file
    for l in reversed(lines): # write the rest of the lines to the file
        f.write(l)
```

It outputs in output.txt:

```
Header
third
second 
first
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(l[0])        
    for l in reversed(lines[1:]):
        f.write(l)
```